# Passing bound struct to view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mobile, swiftui

I am currently trying to refactor some of the SwiftUI code that is used to draw user input so that less of it is contained within the ContentView.

In doing so, I have created a struct that contains most of the stateful elements that are needed to keep track of user drawings.

Here is what that enum looks like:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
struct DrawableStaff{
    var drawing: Drawing = Drawing()
    var drawingList: [Drawing] = [Drawing]()
    var paths: [Path] = [Path]()
    var PathHolder = Path()
    var color = Color.primary
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 3.0
}
```

Next, I refactored the drawing code to better fit the enum:

```
struct DrawingPad: View {
    
    @Binding var drawableStaff: DrawableStaff
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Path { path in
                for drawing in self.drawableStaff.drawings {
                    self.add(drawing: drawableStaff.drawing, toPath: &path)
                }
                self.add(drawing: self.drawableStaff.currentDrawing, toPath: &path)
                self.drawableStaff.pathHolder = path
            }
            .stroke(self.drawableStaff.color, lineWidth: self.drawableStaff.lineWidth)
                .background(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0.1)
                        .onChanged({ (value) in
                            let currentPoint = value.location
                            if currentPoint.y >= 0
                                && currentPoint.y < geometry.size.height {
                                self.drawableStaff.currentDrawing.points.append(currentPoint)
                            }
                        })
                        .onEnded({ (value) in
                            self.drawableStaff.drawings.append(self.currentDrawing)
                            self.drawableStaff.currentDrawing = Drawing()
                        })
            )
                        
            
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
```

I am attempting to call DrawingPad in the ContentView's body by using

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var staff1DrawableStaff = DrawableStaff()    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {            
            let staff1 = ZStack{
                DrawingPad(drawableStaff: $staff1DrawableStaff)
        }
    }
}
```

I am now getting numerous errors regarding the access of the inner members of drawableStaff during the definition of DrawingPad. How do I fix these errors?

"Cannot convert value of type 'Binding' to expected argument type 'Drawing'"

Comment: It does not look like first code snapshot is relative to second one.

Comment: I have added some extra code to the post. Hopefully that helps clarify things

Comment: It looks like you're trying to access the wrong(?) model. You try `self.drawableStaff.currentDrawing` or `self.drawableStaff.drawings`... fields which simply don't exist in `DrawableStaff`.